# How can I encode a filename according to RFC 2231?

Tags: java, rfc2231

I need to encode file attachments at the Content-Disposition HTTP header attribute. I noticed that RFC 2231 is the latest widely-accepted standard and would like to use that. However, I have trouble finding an implementation of that within the core Java SE and Java EE libraries. Do you guys have any recommendations?

A brief search on Google yielded [this](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.4.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/commons/impl/MimeHelper.html) but I ain't sure how trustworthy it is. I was hopping javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility supports RFC 2231 encoding method but it does not appear to (although it did mention RFC 2231 in decoding).

Any input would be welcomed. I am sure this is a common problem for Java web development.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a mess, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http

Comment: I saw that post already. What I am looking for is an implementation.

Comment: what I got from that post is that this mechanism is very unreliable, which is probably why there's no well known implementation of it. I'll adopt the solution given by @porneL

Answer (score 0):

RFC 2231 is related to MIME (sending emails). Regarding HTTP you shoud read RFC 5987 or 6266.

Comment: This seems incorrect: RFC-2388 mentions RFC-2231 for the filename attribute of multipart/form-data : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2388